# Не добавляется анимированный gif весом 1 949 747 байт

Tags: дефект, загрузка-изображения, imgur

При попытке добавить анимированный gif размером 1 949 747 байт (что, естественно, меньше указанного лимита в 2 МБ) получаю странную ошибку:

> Запрос привел к ошибке: [error]

Да и вообще, что за `error`?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Файл для проверки будет предоставлен? Кстати, может быть проблема на стороне imgur и временная. Случаются подобные приколы.

Comment: @alexolut, где бы проблема не была, но выводить так ошибку - плохо, очень плохо!

Comment: @Aid бывает и вовсе классика `Error: No Error`.

Comment: @alexolut, добавился. Наверное, действительно временные проблемы. Вот этот gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk45p.gif

Comment: @Qwertiy: В качестве дополнительной иронии момента, в моём FF вместо скриншота показывается это: http://imgur.com/a/b31Ha

Comment: @VladD, у меня хром, всё показывается.

Comment: @VladD содержит ошибки? У меня такое было тоже. Надо кеш почистить. В чате кажется обсуждалось. Давненько, правда.

Comment: @alexolut, запости ещё баг)

Comment: @Qwertiy о чем?

Comment: @alexolut, о том, что картинки не открываются?

Comment: Это было давно и <s>неправда</s>, как я понял, проблема на клиентской стороне.